# App Engine Flex - Specify Dot Net Runtime version

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I'm building an app with .NET core on Google App Engine flex. These are two top-level items in my app.yaml file...

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
```

Is there a way I can ensure that it runs on the dotnet 2.1 runtime? How do I specify that I want it to run on .NET CORE 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your runtime as **custom** and then create a **Dockerfile** with the runtime configuration you want.
In this case:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:2.1
```

Here you can check the documentation about [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build)

Comment: See also [Customizing the .NET Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/customizing-the-dotnet-runtime).